# learn python the hard way exercise 21 help

Tags: python

hey guys, i spent some time on this one but i find it really hard and cant figure it out. heres what the book says:

> At the end of the script is a puzzle.
>   I’m taking the return value of one
>   function, and using it as the argument
>   of another function. I’m doing this in
>   a chain so that I’m kind of creating a
>   formula using the functions. It looks
>   really weird, but if you run the
>   script you can see the results. What
>   you should do is try to figure out the
>   normal formula that would recreate
>   this same set of operations.

thanks.

```
#functions can return something too
def add(a, b):
    print 'ADDING %d + %d' % (a, b)
    return a + b

def subtract(a, b):
    print 'SUBTRACTING %d - %d' % (a, b)
    return a - b

def multiply(a, b):
    print 'MULTIPLYING %d * %d' % (a, b)
    return a * b

def devide(a, b):
    print 'DEVIDING %d * %d' % (a, b)
    return a / b

age = add(15, 5)
height = subtract(18, 3)
weight = multiply(100, 3)
iq = devide(100, 20)

print 'age: %d, height: %d, weight: %d, iq: %d' % (age, height, weight, iq)

#puzzle for extra credit
what = add(age, subtract(height, multiply(weight, devide(iq, 2))))
print "That becomes: ", what, "Can you do it by hand?"
```

Comment: What exactly is the question? The extra credit is `age + ( heigth - weight * iq / 2 )`...?

Comment: i.e. age = 10, height = 15, weight = 300, iq = 5, what = -725..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to step through this by substituting the body of the function (the non-print statements) into the final function call. I'll start you out:

add(age, subtract(height, multiply(weight, devide(iq, 2))))

becomes:

```
age + subtract(height, multiply(weight, devide(iq, 2)))
```

Comment: That's weird, I almost always go inside out (ie, the first one I'd do is replace `devide(iq, 2)` with `(iq / 2)`).  I assumed everyone did.

Comment: @Daniel DiPaolo: That's correct. That's the way most languages, including Python, would evaluate such a statement. Good example which doesn't is Haskell..

Comment: hehe, i didn't really think about it that much. i just went left to right for the sake of clarity

Comment: Well, it doesn't matter much when evaluating the code by hand ;)

Answer (score 1):

The "normal" formula should be:

```
what = (15+5) + (18-3) - (100*3)*(100/20)/2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
above question you can only call the function. There is no arithmetic can't be performed at time of final function call. Because at final call if you try to add some arithmetic sign there will be show error like:

"**TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'"is question.**

There is shown little form of this question**

from sys import argv
#script=argv def add(a,b):
    print "Addition %d+%d" %(a,b)
    return a+b a=add(34,43) print "add=a %d" %(a) def sub(a,b):
    print "Addition %d-%d" %(a,b)
    return a-b b=sub(234,123) print "sub=a %d" %(b)

d=12 print "New experiment" c=add(a,sub(b,add(a,add(a,b)))) print "Final C=%d" %(c)
```